# Python condition not working, which includes ifelse clause

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I have included the below condition in python, though I have set x as 5 and the 1st condition is False I still receive the output as Test 1

```
x = 5
if [(( 0 < x  <= 1.084) | ((x)  == 0))]:
    print((( 0 < x  <= 1.084) | ((x)  == 0)))
    print('Test1')
elif [(1.084 < x <= 5)]:
    print('Test2')

False
Test1
```

Comment: There are many unnecessary parentheses and the rectangular once are not for term grouping. Also the logical or operator is `or` not `|`.

Comment: `[(( 0 < x <= 1.084) | ((x) == 0))]` is a list. An empty list is False-ish, but all other lists behave like True in an `if` test, even `[False]`.

Comment: For example your if condition could be just `if 0 <= x <= 1.084:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Additional to John's answer, the code for this is just:

```
if 0 <= x <= 1.084:
    print('Test1')
elif 1.084 < x <= 5:
    print('Test2')
```

That's it.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you have the square brackets around your condition, which put the evaluation of the condition (the `False`) inside a Python list (`[False]`).

A Python list will evaluate to true in a boolean context whenever it has any elements, so `[False]` is a valid true condition for the loop.

To fix it, just remove the brackets, which will have the `if` look at `False` instead of the list.

Also, you probably want to use `or` instead of `|`, since the former is the usual operator for booleans and the latter is for integer bitwise or.

You can also get rid of many of the parens, Python usually doesn't need them.

Revised code:

```
x = 5
if (0 < x <= 1.084) or (x == 0):
    print((( 0 < x <= 1.084) | ((x) == 0))) 
    print('Test1')
elif 1.084 < x <= 5:
    print('Test2')
```

Comment: This is great it actually makes sense , i guess the bad guy here is []. since it is evaluating it to True and i got things more complicated with lot of brackets ()

Answer (score 2):

Don't use square brackets in place of parentheses. They're not interchangeable. And use `or` for logical OR, not `|` which is bitwise OR.

```
if ((0 < x <= 1.084) or (x == 0)):
```

Note that none of these parentheses are actually necessary.

```
if 0 < x <= 1.084 or x == 0:
```

And if you change the `<` to `<=` you don't need the second check.

```
if 0 <= x <= 1.084:
```